# Swift - Using PATCH Method to update receive errors

Tags: json, swift, http-method

I am fairly new using API's and been trying to use the API with Airtable. I got the Update API to work with the Rested app. Now I am trying to build my app and utilize the data in the database. The code I am using is:

```
func requestUpdate(completion: @escaping (Result<Codable, Error>) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: baseURL)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.addValue(authorizationToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "PATCH"
    
    do {
        let jsonEncoder = try JSONEncoder().encode(test)
        
        request.httpBody = jsonEncoder
        
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        
        print(response as Any)
        
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This is the Data structure I am using to send to the API:

```
let test: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
    "records": [
        "id": "recG5MIwZ6Tp3OczR",
        "fields": [
            "Goods": "Other",
            "Paid": 1,
            "Sold": 69,
            "Weight": 2,
            "ETA": 2
        ]
    ]
]
```

The basic structure I need is

```
'{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "a id number",
      "fields": {
        "Goods": "Test 1",
        "Paid": 200,
        "Sold": 500,
        "Weight": 120,
        "ETA": 40
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "a id number",
      "fields": {
        "Goods": "Test 2",
        "Paid": 150,
        "Sold": 0,
        "Weight": 10,
        "ETA": 7
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

I even tried creating some simple structs to duplicate this but kept getting an error of Invalid Top-level error in json. Which I am still investigating the error.

I get the error: Status Code: 422, Headers {...} I have only ever used GET method. I am pretty positive I am missing some code with the conversion and all. I think my error could also be with the JSON conversion. Either way I am lost an not sure where to go. Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to encode a `Dictionary<String, Any>` into JSON you better use `JSONSerialisation`.

Alternatively, create an appropriate encodable struct for your "patch spec" (the `Dictionary<String, Any>`):

```
struct Spec: Encodable {
   ...
}
```

and then use `JSONEncoder` to encode the value to JSON.

Either way, in your PATCH request you assign the encoded patch spec value (a `Data`) the `httpBody` parameter from the patch request - as you have already done.

When you receive a result, you perform the mandatory error checks, and if you got a valid response data whose content type is "application/json", you again have two ways to decode it into a value representation:

- Having an appropriate struct which represents the JSON from the response which also conforms to `Decodable`, then you can use `JSONDecoder` to decode the data into the value.
- Otherwise, you can use `JSONSerialisation` and try to decode the JSON into either an `Array<Any>` or `Dictionary<String, Any>` object.

So, basically you have two approaches to decode/encode JSON. I would prefer to use JSONDecoder/JSONEncoder since it provides type safe values, and you have it much easier to deal with them, instead when having a `Dictionary<String, Any>`.

How to make your custom structs conform to `Decodable` and `Encodable` protocol is a different topic and there are numerous questions and answers to this. If you come to a point where you got stuck there, please ask a specific question.

How to make a proper PATCH request is also a different topic. However, the backend should already have defined a proper API for this.

While not always an easy read, the definitive bible for all HTTP related questions are the various "RFC" from the "Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF)". For a deep dive into a PATCH request you find the specification here:
[PATCH Method for HTTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5789)